# LinqPad Explore in Grid editing columns

Tags: linq, sybase, linqpad

We have an HTML column that I cannot seem to edit.  I can edit other columns, but the text in this column is greyed out and it will not let me edit it.

Anyone know how to get around this?

I'm not sure what all is needed from the schema, but here is the info for the specific column

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
html        nvarchar    no       -1                       yes          (n/a)                  (n/a)            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

As you can see the text is grayed out in the html column.  I can edit any other column just fine, but this one for some reason...

[image]

More info.  Some of the HTML columns are editable, but not all of them.  These columns are very large, so I am guessing it is some type of size constraint.

Comment: From a database? From an XML file? from what?

Comment: @user7116 From a database sorry.  I'm able to edit every other column but this one it seems.

Comment: The schema for this table, and the definition of that column in particular, will be helpful. Any sorta screenshot of LINQPad as well.

Comment: @user7116 added info to original post.

Comment: Odd that your column's length is reported as -1. Who reported this number, SQL Management Studio? Is it actually defined `nvarchar(max)` ?

Comment: I got the info from running EXEC sp_help IPACS_Document and yes it is nvarchar(max).  But I think I found the issue.  Some html columns are editing these are the ones I can copy/paste from my clipboard with no data loss.  The ones I cannot edit are ones where I copy to my clipboard and when I paste there is some data loss.

Comment: I'll bet at a certain length the datagrid component used in LINQPad no longer supports editing...maybe. [I'd send LINQPad an email about it](http://www.linqpad.net/feedback.aspx).